# How to get audio stream properties (format and sample rate) of my VoIP provider?

Tags: sip, voip, audio-streaming, pjsip, linphone

I need to integrate [Speech To Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition) (STT) service with IP telephony. STT service support just 5 particular input formats of audio (`MuLaw/ALaw/Linear16/RawOpus/MP3`) and 10 sample rates (`8/11/12/16/22/24/32/44/48/96k`).

How to check which format and sample rate does my VoIP provider use?

Can I do that with [linphone](https://www.linphone.org/)([linphone-cli](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/linphonec.1.html)) or [pyVOIP](https://pypi.org/project/pyVoIP/) or [SIP.js](https://sipjs.com/) or [pjsip](https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject)?

I will be grateful for code or commands examples

Comment: All those sample rates are fine, and I can't think of a a VoIP service that doesn't use some version of PCM or Opus.  Sounds like it'll be quite compatible... and even if it isn't, you can always transcode to PCM or Opus.

Answer (score 1):

Your provider doesn't use anything by itself. The question is what the devices you will call will support.